# Do I have to unwrap an optional before capturing it?

Tags: swift

Say I have this class:

```
class ExpirableClosure {

    let closure: () -> Void
    let isExpired: () -> Bool

    func execute() {

        guard !isExpired() else { return }
        closure()
    }

    init(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void, _ isExpired: @escaping () -> Bool) {

        self.closure = closure; self.isExpired = isExpired
    }
}
```

And then save closures with this method:

```
var savedClosures = [ExpirableClosure]()
func saveClosure(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void, expireWith object: AnyObject? = nil) {

    let isExpired = (object != nil) ? { [weak object] in object == nil } : { false }
    savedClosures.append(ExpirableClosure(closure, isExpired))
}
```

Will capturing the optional before unwrapping it result in the `ExpirableClosure` expiring right away because the only strong reference to the optional is destroyed when the function terminates?

### Update

If you run this code:

```
class Object {}
var handle: Object? = Object()
saveClosure({}, expireWith: handle)
print(savedClosures.first!.isExpired()) // prints false
handle = nil
print(savedClosures.first!.isExpired()) // prints true
```

on [this online compiler](https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=swift) you get those print statements. So is swift unwrapping the optional behind the scenes here and weakly referencing its value?
 Why else would `isExpired` ever return false, or return true after setting `handle` to `nil`?

Comment: You could instead pass the non-optional object - it doesn't make much sense to start with a nil (aka expired) object right from the start.

Comment: @Cristik It does if the closure is not meant to expire. Then the caller only has to provide the `closure` parameter when calling the function because the `object` parameter has a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Your "handle" variable has the only strong reference to the object until it is set to nil.  At that point, the optional "object" variable in { [weak object] in object == nil } becomes nil because it is a weak reference and the condition returns true.

If you had no other strong reference to the expiring object then the entry would be expired right away:

```
// for example
saveClosure({}, expireWith: Object())
print(savedClosures.first!.isExpired()) // would print true
```